# Adding due dates to checkbox items

Tags: org-mode

This is my `todo.org` file:

```
* Personal [/]
 - [ ] Wash car
 - [ ] Take out trash

* Work
 - [ ] Call boss
 - [ ] Email client
```

Which renders on (spacemacs + osx) as:

[image]

I'd like to add a due date to each checkbox item, but every time I try to add a date, it gets added to work or personal, instead of each item.

How can I add due dates to each checkbox item?

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to add specific dates to different tasks is to use TODO items; in your case, level 2 headings with TODO keywords.

[You can add progress statistics for subheadings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Breaking-down-tasks.html) as you did for checkboxes.

Checkboxes are rather limited in functionality whereas TODO headings allow for all the goodies: dates, scheduled and deadline specification, priorities, several states, custom properties, dependencies, etc.